# How can i use (:= operator) with the loop for?

Tags: python

Why this code is false? it says: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
How can i use (:= operator) with the loop for?

```
for j in x := list(zip(*[re.split("\W+",open(sys.argv[1],'r',encoding="utf-8").read().lower())[i:] for i in range(int(sys.argv[2]))])):
 d = {j: x.count(j) for j in set(x)}

[print(" ".join(k)+" "+str(d.get(k))+"\n") for k in sorted(d) if d.get(k)==int(sys.argv[3]) and re.search("^\w{"+sys.argv[4]+"} (.+ )?\w{"+sys.argv[5]+"}$"," ".join(k))]
```

Comment: If you have troubles to find an error in your code, you should try to break it down into parts instead of running everything in one line. That will make it more readable and "Readability counts." –The Zen of Python

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parentheses with the Walrus Operator.

This works

```
for x in (y := [1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
```

But this does not

```
for x in y := [1, 2, 3]:
    print(x)
```

However, you should consider refactoring your code.  There does not seem to be any purpose to re-assigning to `d` over and over in your loop, and it would be more efficient to pre-calculate `set(x)`

Comment: @amdzazda You can accept his answer if it helped you by clicking **tickmark** to left side of his answer below downvote option